# Как получить привычный для глаз вид float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, float, format

Если разделить `100` на `1000000`, Python выведет результат: `0.0001`

Если же поделить на миллион число меньше `100`, то результат будет такого вида:

```
>>>print(68 / 1000000)
6.8e-05
```

а хотелось бы видеть это: `0.000068`

---

Причины такого вывода понятны, но все же, этот результат должен выводиться в GUI. Пользователь, который увидит такое значение, может испугаться и навсегда перестать пользоваться компьютером )

Как получить привычный для глаз вид `float`, при делении числа меньше 100 на миллион?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться услугами форматированных строк. Флаг `F` приводит значение к виду обычного действительного числа. Если вам нужно будет провести обратную операцию (вывести обычное число с плавающей точкой в экспоненциальном виде) - к вашим услугам флаг `e`.

```
>>> a = 31/1000000
>>> a
3.1e-05
>>> '{0:F}'.format(a)
'0.000031'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> a = 68 / 1000000
>>> print(a)
6.8e-05
```

То же, но с использованием [f-строки](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method) (python 3.6):

```
>>> print(f'{a:f}')
0.000068
```

То же, но с указанием точности после запятой:

```
>>> print(f'{a:.7f}')
0.0000680
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 1/1221759
'{0:.10f}'.format(a)

'0.0000008185'
```

просто вам не нужна экспоненциальная форма записи чисел с плавающей запятой

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801586/print-a-float-number-in-normal-form-not-exponential-form-scientific-notation